# Everytime i do any changes to java code, it won't reflect after i saves the file

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven, eclipse-jee

I am using Eclipse Neon for my java project, every time I do any changes to java code, it **won't reflect** after I save the file (for ex: a simple syso statement). I have to do **maven clean and maven install** my project then restarts the boot.

Comment: Eclipse Neon is 11 releases behind. Do not waste time by using outdated software. Please tell the command line used to run it (in the run configuration there is a button _Show Command Line_ to get the command line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add devtools dependency to your project in pom.xml (if spring boot project) :-

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And enable Build Automatically in eclipse :-

[image]

Comment: build automatically is enabled already, thing is any code doesnot reflect unless i maven clean install and i tired to add above change in pom.xml it gives me this error

Comment: Application run failed Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean. at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:205) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE] –

Comment: Please show your pom.xml and stack trace

Comment: <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </exclusion>

   </exclusions>
   <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: share complete pom.xml not just couple of dependencies

Comment: copy paste this link in browser

Comment: https://ctxt.io/2/AAAgowoCFA

Comment: Is it a web application or not?

Comment: i pasted dependecy here

Comment: yes , it is a web application

Comment: In devtools dependency giver version - <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version> instead of 1.5.3.RELEASE

Comment: hi gaurav, there was some dependencies issues which was not showing while project clean and install, by making new workspace and updating project resolve that. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that Build Automatically option in `Project->Build Automatically`, is enabled.

Also try to update the project using Mvn > update project

Comment: build automatically is enabled already, thing is any code doesnot reflect unless i maven clean install
and i tired to add above change in pom.xml
it gives me this error: